# Как задать первому элементу из списка класс active?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php while($slider -> have_posts()) :  $slider->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="slide">
          <div class="slide-top"><?php the_title();?></div>
          <div class="slide-bottom"><?php the_content();?></div>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
        </div>

      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Добрый день есть такой код. Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать что бы у первого элемента из цикла
был класс active

К примеру выведет 3 элемента с классом slide а первый будет иметь и класс active

Comment: Добавить счетчик и делать по нему проверку

Answer (score 1):

**current_post** - Индекс отображаемого сообщения.

```
<?php while($slider -> have_posts()) :  $slider->the_post(); ?>
  <div class="slide <?php if ( $slider->current_post == 0 ) : ?>active<?php endif; ?>">
     <div class="slide-top"><?php the_title();?></div>
     <div class="slide-bottom"><?php the_content();?></div>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
  </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $i=0; while($slider -> have_posts()): $slider->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="slide<?php if ($i === 0) echo ' active';?>">
      <div class="slide-top"><?php the_title();?></div>
      <div class="slide-bottom"><?php the_content();?></div>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
    </div>
  <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Он же просит первому, а вы присваиваете второму.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил